# Why does only first letter gets printed of name?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cin

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int age;
    char name;
    cout<<"Enter age and name: ";
    cin >> age >> name;
    cout <<endl <<"your age: "<< age << endl << "name is: "<< name;


    return 0;
}
```

What a run looks like:

[image]

Comment: How many letters do you expect to store in a single `char` variable?

Comment: The variable `char name` only can hold one letter.  You need a character array to hold an entire word.

Comment: `char name` -> `std::string name` and away you go. Also I'd parse separately in case someone has a name that begins with a number - allowable in some jurisdictions.

Answer (score 1):

Use a string instead of a char. A character only gets the first letter of the input.
The code should look like this.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int age = 0;
    string name = "";
    
    cout<<"Enter your age and name: ";
    
    cin >> age >> name;
    
    cout << endl;
    
    cout << "Your age is " << age << endl;
    cout << "Your name is " << name << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

If you are required to use a character, you can try using a vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<char> _myStr;

void DisplayList () {
    cout << "Your name is: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < _myStr.size(); i++) {
        cout << _myStr[i];
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void ConvertToVector (string theStr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < theStr.length(); i++) {
        _myStr.push_back(theStr[i]);
    }
}

int main () {
    int age = 0;
    string name = "";

    cout << "Enter your age and name: ";
    cin >> age >> name;

    cout << endl;

    ConvertToVector (name);   

    cout << "Your age is: " << age;
    DisplayList ();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string instead of char...

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int age;
    string name;
    cout<<"Enter age and name: ";
    cin >> age >> name;
    cout <<endl <<"your age: "<< age << endl << "name is: "<< name;


    return 0;
}
```